# Vim disable make on insert mode exit

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using yats (https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim) for typescript, it sets the `makeprg` variable, which makes it so vim runs `make` everytime I make a change to a file. I would like to somehow disable this, as I prefer a linter manager (ALE), which can compile and also lint.
Is there something I can do about that localy or does `yats` need an option to disable the setting of `makeprg`?

EDIT:
The accepted answer doesn't provide actual solution to my specific problem, but the explanation of `makeprg` guided me in the right direction, which was other plugins. I traced the problem back to YouCompleteMe.

Comment: "*it sets the `makeprg` variable, which makes it so vim runs `make` everytime I make a change to a file*" - No, that's not what `makeprg` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it sets the `makeprg` variable, which makes it so vim runs `make` everytime I make a change to a file.

No, `makeprg` only defines what external command to run when you or a plugin does `:make`.

Furthermore, I couldn't find anything in that plugin that would run `:make` on write or on any other event. The command below will hopefully help you find where that automatic `make` comes from:

```
:verbose autocmd BufWritePost
```

See `:help :verbose`, `:help :autocmd`, `:help BufWritePost`.

Comment: I'm sorry, the statement about `makeprg` was poorly structured, probably should've said something like "it seems to make vim run...". Which is also false, but I didn't get this behaviour in other filetypes and I thought it was wierd there was nothing in the vim help.

About the verbose thing, it's definetly not a `BufWritePost` autocmd, as it runs when I exit insert mode, do a replace or even open a file. I tried it with `BufEnter` and no luck.

Comment: But thanks to your explanation of makeprg, I was able to use the `disable other plugins` way and trace it back to YouCompleteMe. Which doesn't actually run `make` but instead manages the errors itself.